# SVG Multiple pages

Tags: layout, web, svg, web-standards

What is the status of extending SVG standard to support multiple pages, aka `pageSet`?

I saw that few years ago SVG 1.2 and SVG Print initiatives slowly went to halt so I'm wondering whether someone has current info on the future features of SVG? What about other extensions beyond `pageSet`?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently found a multi-page extension for Inkscape.
http://inkscape-pages.sourceforge.net/

Now taking it for a test run.

MarkT

Comment: Could you please link to that extension? I cannot find it... Is it built-in into Inkscape?